# node silently closes requests with literal space in url

Tags: node.js, http

Let's start simple server:

```js
var http = require('http');    
http.createServer(function (req, res) {
    console.log('asdasd');
    res.end('asdasd');
}).listen(8898)
```

And make a simple request

```
curl -v 'localhost:8898/?ab'
*   Trying ::1...
* Connected to localhost (::1) port 8898 (#0)
> GET /?ab HTTP/1.1
> Host: localhost:8898
> User-Agent: curl/7.43.0
> Accept: */*
>
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Date: Thu, 13 Oct 2016 20:26:14 GMT
< Connection: keep-alive
< Content-Length: 6
<
* Connection #0 to host localhost left intact
asdasd
```

Looks like everything is all right.
But if we add a literal space to it...

```
cornholio-osx:~/>curl -v 'localhost:8898/?a b'
*   Trying ::1...
* Connected to localhost (::1) port 8898 (#0)
> GET /?a b HTTP/1.1
> Host: localhost:8898
> User-Agent: curl/7.43.0
> Accept: */*
>
* Empty reply from server
* Connection #0 to host localhost left intact
```

Nothing is logged and no body is written.

I assume, literal spaces in URLs are violation of HTTP protocol but is this behavior HTTP-complaint?

Comment: Potentially. What you have requested is the root page with query param `a` using protocol `b` (the string after the space is the HTTP protocol version). Since node does not support protocol `b` it does not know how to answer so it can ignore the request - it's not an HTTP request but a `b` request.

Comment: Note that the protocol does not need to be http. Node could very well receive `GET /?a SPDY/1.0` and that would NOT be a HTTP request. If node supports SPDY version 1.0 it can respond. If not is should not because responding the wrong thing may break the requesting application.

Comment: @slebetman - Why don't you write an answer?

Comment: Note that if we make `GET /?a HTTP/1.1 HTTP/1.1` request, result will be the same. Looks like it's not a `b` request to node but if HTTP Request-Line is malformed in any way, node just closes the connection silently.

Comment: your space must be **url encoded** (%20), any space character in the first line of the query is a separator. Node is right to close the connection because usually bad HTTP syntax is either coming from attackers (strange http syntax leads to http smuggling) or from bad bots. No browser would send a space without url encoding it.